# Validating date input field with onsubmit

Tags: javascript, php

I was looking everywhere, but I couldn't find a good code for my problem. 
I have some input fields, what the users are using to send online their requests.
And one of the fields is a date field, what I would like somehow to validate in that way, that to be allowed only if the entered date to be somewhere between today and 8  days before.
Example: if today is 29 November , they would be allowed to enter only date between 21st-29th November and nothing else
And to be shown an alert window already when they have entered the wrong date
They will pick up the days from minicalendar but that part is resolved, I need help only with the validating.
If somebody could post a working code, I would be very grateful. 
Thank you

Comment: You should probably use moment, and probably rome too

Comment: You could use a for()-loop and then write a variable if the validation is without errors (e.g. correct date) and if the variable isn't written (or not set true) you can throw an error.

Comment: [jQuery UI Datepicker](http://jqueryui.com/datepicker/#min-max)

Comment: @Rafael Actually jQuery UI DP doesn't prevent anyone from just manually typing in a different date than actually allowed.

Comment: Rome does, and rome validates

Comment: Check out rome on git here https://github.com/bevacqua/rome

Comment: @Shiala I was only talking about the datepicker from jQuery UI. I don't really know Rome.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois hmmmm

Comment: I know, but if you ever need a datepicker with all flavors and cool spices  you should consider rome, only dependency is moment but who doesn't use moment

Comment: @Shiala Also never heard of moment. So... that would be me.

Comment: @CharlotteDunois Moment.js is a very cool dateformatter with date validation and stuff like that you should check it out

Comment: [bootstrap datepicker](https://github.com/eternicode/bootstrap-datepicker)

Answer (score 0):

Use jQuery UI DatePicker, the script below:

```
    $(function() {
    var currentDate = new Date();
    var maxAllowedDate = new Date(currentDate);
    maxAllowedDate.setDate(currentDate.getDate() + 8);
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({ 
        changeYear: true,
        minDate: '0',
        maxDate: '+7D',
    });
    $('#datepicker').change(function(){
     var enteredVal = new Date(this.value);
        if(enteredVal.getTime() < currentDate.getTime() || enteredVal.getTime() > maxAllowedDate.getTime()) {
            alert("invalid");
        } else {
            alert("valid");
        }
    });
});
```

and the UI:

```
<div class="demo">

<p>Date: <input type="text" id="datepicker"></p>
```

Here is the jsFiddle demo: http://jsfiddle.net/pjkz7k0t/1/

Comment: Look at @CharlotteDunois comment above

Comment: @Shiala Using DatePicker to set allowed min and max date range eliminates the needs to validate the date if it is within 8 days. This achieves what the user wants using jQuery UI (not another plugin library) and prevents invalid date input.

Comment: Thanks IsabelHM… You gave me a good idea, and code, but the problem is, if they will ignore the mini calendar, they can put the date by hand even if the can't choose from mini calendar...

Comment: I need something to block definitely the users to enter a date out range

Comment: I added validation to datepicker onChange event

Comment: Yes, now it's better, but even if they get an alert window saying invalid, when they press the Ok button, the manually typed date remain in the field, so they can continue even if they entered an invalid date…How should I clear the field if is invalid? Thank you

Comment: are you trying to learn to code or to get someone else to write a complete solution? so far, no upvote and not selected as answer; I think you can do the rest on your own. Set a local boolean isValid to false if onchange return invalid. then only enable the ok button if isValid is true. @user2167180

Answer (score 0):

Since you asked for javascript, I will assume you want a javascript answer, not a jQuery answer.

```
function isValidDate(checkDate) {
    if(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d/.test(checkDate)) {
        // split checkDate into three pieces
        var strMM = checkDate.split('/')[0];
        var strDD = checkDate.split('/')[1];
        var strYYYY = checkDate.split('/')[2];

        // create new Date() object from split pieces
        var strDateCheck = new Date(strYYYY,(strMM - 1),strDD); 

        // evaluate each piece of resulting date object against each corresponding piece of checkDate
        if(((strDateCheck.getMonth() + 1) == strMM) && (strDateCheck.getDate() == strDD) && (strDateCheck.getFullYear() == strYYYY)) {
            /* if you wish, add additional validation constraints here */
            return true; // all three pieces match exactly
        }
    }
    return false; // did not meet criteria for return true
}
```

This method uses explicit regex to validate the formats.

Instead of creating elaborate methods of testing each piece, I used the pieces to build a new Date() object, knowing that the result MIGHT not match checkDate, and used pieces from resulting date to test the pieces of checkDate passed into the function. If ALL THREE pieces match, the entered date is valid.

For instance:

'02/29/2014' returns false

'02/29/2012' returns true

'12/36/2014' returns false

'29/06/2014' returns false

The code is pure javascript which improves portability, and this method does not interfere or impede additional validation by any other criteria you choose to use (against year ranges, or evaluating strCheckDate against today(), or any other constraints specific to your specific application).

An added advantage is that this method does not just determine whether what is passed to the function can be used to create a valid date, but confirms that the date entered MATCHES the valid date that can be created (thereby overcoming the problem of javascript rolling "extra days" forward on date creation).

This could easily be expanded to test for various configurations of date, using the exact same logic, simply by creating a different regex test, and splitting checkDate differently.

regex for DD/MM/YYYY would be the same, but the split would look like this:

```
        // split characters into three pieces
        var strDD = checkDate.split('/')[0];
        var strMM = checkDate.split('/')[1];
        var strYYYY = checkDate.split('/')[2];
```

Or for YYYY/MM/DD you would use regex:

```
        /\d\d\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d/.test(checkDate)
```

and the split would look like this:

```
        // split characters into three pieces
        var strYYYY = checkDate.split('/')[0];
        var strMM = checkDate.split('/')[1];
        var strDD = checkDate.split('/')[2];
```

This is highly morphable (and clean) javascript code to accomplish the purpose of validating a user entered date, and can be quickly modified to expand checks for valid date within range.

```
function isValidDateRange(checkDate,minDate,maxDate) {
    if(/\d\d\/\d\d\/\d\d\d\d/.test(checkDate)) {
        // split checkDate into three pieces
        var strMM = checkDate.split('/')[0];
        var strDD = checkDate.split('/')[1];
        var strYYYY = checkDate.split('/')[2];

        // create new Date() object from split pieces
        var strDateCheck = new Date(strYYYY,(strMM - 1),strDD); 

        // evaluate each piece of resulting date object against each corresponding piece of checkDate
        if(((strDateCheck.getMonth() + 1) == strMM) && (strDateCheck.getDate() == strDD) && (strDateCheck.getFullYear() == strYYYY)) {
            // if this code fires, you have a valid date entered, first logic hurdle passed
            // If you pass in minDate and maxDate as any format other than a date object, you should
            // create new Date(); from them before comparing.
            // Example:
            // var strMinMM = minDate.split('/')[0];
            // var strMinDD = minDate.split('/')[1];
            // var strMinYYYY = minDate.split('/')[2];
            // minDate = new Date(strMinYYYY,(strMinMM - 1),strMinDD);
            // var strMaxMM = maxDate.split('/')[0];
            // var strMaxDD = maxDate.split('/')[1];
            // var strMaxYYYY = maxDate.split('/')[2];
            // maxDate = new Date(strMaxYYYY,(strMaxMM - 1),strMaxDD);
            if((!strDateCheck < minDate) && (!strDateCheck > maxDate)) {
                return true; // all three pieces match exactly AND date is within specified range
            }
        }
    }
    return false; // did not meet criteria for return true
}
```